# Response for prelight has invalid HTTP status code error javascript

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js

I am building an app in vue.js and using axios for my http requests. I am trying to make a request to a 3rd party API but I keep getting
    `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403`. However, the exact same request works if I use postman. My request:

```
axios({
  method: "get",
  url: "www.xxx.com/api/v1/xxx",
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    authorization: authToken,
    accept: 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => {
  // do something 
}).catch(err => {
  // handle error
})
```

Note - I am using google chrome and have the CORS extension activated.

Can someone help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So they do not support preflight...

Comment: Why do you have a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your request? It is a response header. It is nonsense to put it on a request.

Comment: Why do you have a `Content-Type` header on your request? It is a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content type of.

Comment: "I am using google chrome and have the CORS extension activated" — The CORS extension is a dirty hack that doesn't handle preflight requests properly.

Comment: thanks for the feedback - could you advise what I should do then? @Quentin all the tutorials i've read so far tell me to add `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',`, but that gives me `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. `

Comment: The tutorials should be telling you to add that to the **response**, not the request.